# Game over on only certain collisions Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, collision

I'm learning a little bit of corona/lua, and am building a small game. In it, there are multiple in-game cars being spawned, and the player has to avoid them with his/her own. If a collision occurs, the game is over. My problem is that sometimes the in-game cars spawn on top of each other, causing a collision, and thus ending the game prematurely/without fault of the player. How can I fix my collision code/spawn rate to fix this? The code is messy I know, but please bear with me!

Any help/code critique is greatly appreciated.

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Sean Lyons
    -- main.lua
    -- Game Programming project - vertical scroller
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    local physics = require "physics" -- Physics Engine
    physics.start()
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    --globals
    _W = display.contentWidth
    _H = display.contentHeight
    scrollSpeed = 6
    carSpeed = 4
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --variables 
    local compCollisionFilter = { categoryBits = 2, maskBits = 0 }
    local playerCollisionFilter = { categoryBits = 2, maskBits = 0 }
    local level2
    local userPaddle
    local background
    local background2
    local background3
    local crashSound = audio.loadSound( "crash.wav" )
    local engineSound = audio.loadStream("engine1n.wav")
    local userCarSound = audio.play(engineSound, {channel = 1, loops =-1, fadein=5000} )
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --spritesheet
    local options =
    {
    width = 37,
    height = 100,
    numFrames = 5
    }
    local sheet = graphics.newImageSheet("images/carsprites.png", options )
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --background images (Multiple for scrolling)
    background = display.newImageRect("images/background.png", 320, 480)
    background:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
    background.x = 0
    background.y = _H/2

    background2 = display.newImageRect("images/background.png", 320, 480)
    background2:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
    background2.x = 0
    background2.y = background.y+480

    background3 = display.newImageRect("images/background.png", 320, 480)
    background3:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
    background3.x = 0
    background3.y = background2.y+480
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --player car
    userPaddle = display.newImage("images/car.png", 100, 380)
    local carGroup = display.newGroup()
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --scrolling background
    local function move( event )
    background.y = background.y + scrollSpeed
    background2.y = background2.y + scrollSpeed
    background3.y = background3.y + scrollSpeed
    if (background.y + background.contentWidth) > 1045 then
        background:translate( 0, -960)
    end
    if (background2.y + background2.contentWidth) > 1045 then
        background2:translate(0, -960)
    end
    if (background3.y + background3.contentWidth) > 1045 then
        background3:translate(0, -960)
    end
    end

    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", move)
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --sprite generator
    function loadSprite()
    frame1 = display.newImage( sheet, math.random(5))
    frame1.x = 10 + math.random(100)
    frame1.y = -110
    frame1.y = frame1.y + carSpeed
    frame2 = display.newImage( sheet, math.random(4))
    frame2.x = frame1.x + 60
    frame2.y = -170
    frame2.y = frame2.y + carSpeed
    frame3 = display.newImage( sheet, math.random(4))
    frame3.x = frame2.x + 90
    frame3.y = -230
    frame3.y = frame3.y + carSpeed
    carGroup:insert(frame1)
    carGroup:insert(frame2)
    carGroup:insert(frame3)
    end
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --car scrolling
    local function carMove( event )
    frame2.y = frame2.y + carSpeed
    frame3.y = frame3.y + carSpeed
    frame1.y = frame1.y + carSpeed
    if (frame2.y + frame2.contentWidth) > 605 then
        frame2:removeSelf()
        frame2 = display.newImage(sheet, math.random(4))
        frame2.x = 40 + math.random(100)
        physics.addBody(frame2, "dynamic", {density = 5, friction = .05,
        bounce = .05})
        frame2:translate( 0, -1100)
    end
    if (frame3.y + frame3.contentWidth) > 605 then
        frame3:removeSelf()
        frame3 = display.newImage(sheet, math.random(4))
        frame3.x = frame2.x + math.random(100)
        physics.addBody(frame3, "dynamic", {density = 5, friction = .05,
        bounce = .05})
        frame3:translate(0, -1400)
    end
    if (frame1.y + frame1.contentWidth) > 600 then
        frame1:removeSelf()
        frame1 = display.newImage(sheet, math.random(4))
        frame1.x = frame3.x + math.random(60)
        physics.addBody(frame1, "dynamic", {density = 5, friction = .05,
        bounce = .05})
        frame1:translate(0, -1200)
    end
    end

    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", carMove) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Set up physics
function startPhysics()
    physics.addBody(userPaddle, "dynamic", {density = 5, friction = .05,
        bounce = .1, filter = {userCollisionFilter}})
    physics.addBody(frame2, "dynamic", {density = 5, friction = .05,
        bounce = .05, filter = {compCollisionFilter}})
    physics.addBody(frame3, "dynamic", {density = 5, friction = .05,
        bounce = .05, filter = {compCollisionFilter}})
    physics.addBody(frame1, "dynamic", {density = 5, friction = .05,
        bounce = .05, filter = {compCollisionFilter}})
    physics.setGravity(0, 0)
end
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--drag event
function userPaddle:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        self.markX = self.x -- store x location of object
        self.markY = self.y -- store y location of object

    elseif event.phase =="moved" then
        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY

        self.x, self.y = x, y -- move object based on calculations above

    end
    return true
end
userPaddle:addEventListener( "touch", userPaddle )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local timeLimit = 0
timerUp = display.newText(timeLimit, 300, 500, native.systemFontBold, 14)
timerUp:setTextColor(0,0,0)

local function timeUP(event)
    if (scrollSpeed ~= 0) then
        timeLimit = timeLimit+1
        timerUp.text = timeLimit
        if (timeLimit == 3) then
            level2()
        end

    elseif (scrollSpeed == 0) then
        local gameOver = display.newText("Game Over!", 105, 40, native.systemFontBold, 24)
        gameOver:setTextColor(255, 10, 0)
    end
end
timer.performWithDelay(1000,timeUP,timeLimit)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--add increased spawn rate here
function level2()   
    frame4 = display.newImage( sheet, math.random(4))
    frame4.x = frame3.x + 60
    frame4.y = -310
    carGroup:insert(frame4)
    physics.addBody(frame4, "dynamic", {density = 5, friction = .05,
    bounce = .05, filter = {compCollisionFilter}})
    carSpeed= carSpeed + 1
    scrollSpeed = scrollSpeed + 1
    frame4.y = frame4.y + carSpeed
    carGroup:insert(frame4)
end
function levelTwo(event)
if timeLimit >= 3 then
    frame4.y = frame4.y + carSpeed
    if (frame4.y + frame4.contentWidth) > 600 then
        frame4:removeSelf()
        frame4 = display.newImage(sheet, math.random(4))
        frame4.x = frame3.x + math.random(60)
        physics.addBody(frame4, "dynamic", {density = 5, friction = .05,
        bounce = .05, filter = {compCollisionFilter}})
        frame4:translate(0, -2000)
    end
end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", levelTwo)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--collision event
local function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began") then
        print( "began: collision")
        scrollSpeed = 0
        carSpeed = 0
        userCarSound = audio.stop()
        local crashSound = audio.play( crashSound, { channel=2, loops=0, fadein=0 }  ) 
    elseif ( event.phase =="ended" ) then
        --outPutField:removeSelf()
        if (outPutField ~= nil) then
            outPutField:removeSelf()
        end
        print( "ended: collision")
        end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
loadSprite()
startPhysics()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the collision event handler, check that the collision is with the user's car. If not, delete the new car and continue (ignore the collision).